# Проблемы с json android помогите разобраться

Tags: android, json, post

Я отправляю из своего приложения на сервер запрос при помощи метода post и вот у меня почему-то конвертированный пароль не соответствует оригиналу, например, я отсылаю `password!123`, а на сервер идет `password%2123`. Не могу понять в чем проблема, может конечно нужно как-то перегонять свой пароль в какой-то другой формат прежде чем он будет конвертироваться в json. Если кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой или знает как решить мою буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: а вы отсылаете запрос в сыром json формате или в Form Url Encoded?

Comment: насколько я вижу Form Url Encoded

Comment: попробуйте отсылать Raw Body (@Body если ретрофит). тогда оно не будет енкодить символы

Comment: и в хедер ещё контент тайп засуньте чтобы уж наверняка ;)

Comment: а если у меня написано @Field  то оно не подойдет для поставленной задачи?? Потому-что я как-бы вытаскиваю данные из полей для ввода

Comment: тут надо у бекенда вашего спрашивать. если они ждут чистый json то @ Body если они ждут форму то @ FormUrlEncoded и @ Field

Comment: чистый json, просто если я делаю  такой запрос Call<LoginRequest> savePost(@Body LoginRequest body); то нужно ли что-то еще менять? и я не сильно понял где создавать метод savepost ну или как-то по другому названный метод, и за что он отвечает?